# ELK 8 Error: Unable to create a type in an index Elasticsearch. "no handler found for uri and method POST" on trying to create a type from Postman

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am very new to ELK and trying to post some document in an index. I'm using elk 8.0

First I've created an index using postman and it was successful
http://localhost:9200/testdb
[image]

However, whenever I'm trying to create a 'type' and add some document into it, I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": "no handler found for uri [/testdb/people] and method [POST]"
}
```

[image]

Can somebody please help on this? As I said, I'm pretty new to ELK and not able to identify what is it that I'm missing here

Answer (score 2):

For Elasticsearch 8.x

> Specifying types in requests is no longer supported.

Please refer to [Removal Of Mapping Types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/removal-of-types.html#removal-of-types)